# C# - Operating on multidimensional List<string[,]> - adding items

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

From past hour i try to get into adding items into multidimensional list. Below is short program code:

```
        List<string[,]> nums = new List<string[,]>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
            {

            }
        }
```

Now, i try to add items in order:

```
nums[0,0] = i+j;
nums[0,1] = i+j;
nums[1,0] = i+j;
```

and go on. 
Should i code this completly diffrent way to make a dynamic 2 dimensional array where i can add items via for interation or there is way of using for example "Add" / "AddRange" function to do this?

When i try to use for example

```
nums[i].Add(Convert.ToString(i));
```

I end up with error:

Error   CS1061  'string[*,*]' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'string[*,*]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Same goes for AddRange.

Honestly, i searched in google and answers what i found was mainly related to static multidimensional arrays, already implemented into code.
I am not experienced with arrays and will be gratefull for help to fix this problem.

Thank you for help and wish you good day/night.
Regards,
Michal

Comment: Do you know  that you have list of 2-dimential arrays? And the right syntax will be `nums[i][j,k] = "SomeString";`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nums` is not your array it's the list which have been initialized. You should initialize an array, fill it and then add it to the the list like

```
    List<string[,]> nums = new List<string[,]>();
    string[,] arr1 = new string[10, 10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
        {
          arr1[i,j] = "Test"; // for example
        }
    }

   nums.Add(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are trying to use a `List<string[,]>` as a 2D array. Maybe you just wanted a `List<string[]>` which would be a list of 1D arrays and would make sense for you to use as nums[1][0] = xxx. It also seems you are storing integer values as strings so maybe you wanted int[,] or `List<int[]>`.

If you want to be able to use Add and Remove and have this be dynamic, you could use `List<List<string>>` (or int). Then you could use:

```
nums.Add(new List<string>());
nums.Add(new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" });
nums[nums.Count - 1].Add("4");
```

And so on.

If you really want to add to `List<string[,]>` then use:

```
nums.Add(new string[4, 4]); // or whatever ranges
nums[nums.Count - 1][0, 1] = "1";
```